# Joins in Yii class CDBCriteria?

Tags: sql, yii

Could anyone help me convert this following SQL statement (which works in my database) to the Yii framework CDbCriteria class format?

Here is my SQL:

SELECT cars.*, 3963 * acos(cos(radians(53.376217)) * cos(radians(car_dealers.latitude)) * cos(radians(-1.499595) - radians(car_dealers.longitude)) + sin(radians(53.376217)) * sin(radians(car_dealers.latitude))) AS distance FROM cars JOIN car_dealers ON cars.company_id=car_dealers.company_id WHERE cars.make='Fiat' AND cars.model='Punto' ORDER BY distance;

Here is my Yii attempt:

```
$criteria= new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->alias = 'cars';
$criteria->select= 'cars.*, 3963 * acos(cos(radians(53.376217)) * cos(radians(car_dealers.latitude)) * cos(radians(-1.499595) - radians(car_dealers.longitude)) + sin(radians(53.376217)) * sin(radians(car_dealers.latitude))) AS distance';
$criteria->join='JOIN car_dealers ON cars.company_id=car_dealers.company_id';
$criteria->condition= 'make=:make AND model=:model'; 
$criteria->params= array('[:make] => Fiat,[:model] => Punto')
$criteria->order='distance';
```

Thank you very much in advance to anyone who can help! :)

Comment: what is the error you are getting? Please give more details.
right off the bat, i can see that you are using params wrongly -
$criteria->params = array(':make'=>'Fiat', ':model'=>'Punto');

Comment: Basically my object is coming back with all the values in the cars table based on that params fine but isnt bring back the distance value back into the object.

Comment: i hope you have declared $distance variable in Car model class

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here

```
$criteria->params= array('[:make] => Fiat,[:model] => Punto')
```

It should be:

```
$criteria->params= array(':make' => 'Fiat',':model' => 'Punto')
```